# Nautilus: changing a file icon from command line

Tags: command-line, nautilus, icons

I know how to change the icon of a specific file via Nautilus : right click > Properties [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z0H6.png).
Is there a way to do the same action from the terminal? At least, does someone know where is stored the path to the icon for a specific file?

I am not interested in creating a `.desktop` file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gio for this. For instance, to set it to `text-x-plain`, you could do:

```
gio set <location> metadata::custom-icon-name text-x-plain
```

Comment: Yes! `gio` is the solution. Here is the exact command I used: `gio set file_to_add_icon_to  'metadata::custom-icon'  'file:///path/to/the/icon/file'`